# TI CC2650STK - how to control onboard LED through iOS app

Tags: objective-c, xcode, microcontroller, sigabrt

I am using this code from this repository: https://git.ti.com/sensortag-ios-source-code-example/sensortag-ios-source-code-example

I am trying to turn on the red onboard LED of the CC2650STK when the object temperature sensor exceeds 30°C and turn it off when the temperature is below 30°C again.

I'm not even sure if my current approach is correct but I'm stuck here. Does somebody know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

I did not change the hardware's firmware

I have already added the following into the "calcValue" method in the 'sensorTagAmbientTemperatureService.m' file:

```
if (tObj >= 30.0){
    uint8_t valueRedLedOn = 0x01;
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:&valueRedLedOn length:sizeof(valueRedLedOn)];
    [self.btHandle writeValue:data toCharacteristic:TI_SENSORTAG_IO_CONFIG];
    redLedOn = true;
}
else {
    if(redLedOn == true){
        uint8_t valueRedLedOff = 0x00;
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:&valueRedLedOff length:sizeof(valueRedLedOn)];
        [self.btHandle writeValue:data toCharacteristic:TI_SENSORTAG_IO_CONFIG];
        redLedOn = false;
    }
}
```

but when the app is running and the temperature reaches 30°C, I get a SIGABRT error (also see the log output):

[screenshot of error w code and log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxsoS.png)

[repository with my changes](https://git.ti.com/~kerstinw/sensortag-ios-source-code-example/kerstinws-sensortag-ios-source-code-example/commits/SensorTag_kerstin)

Comment: The interesting part of the log is `[__NSCFConstantString peripheral]`.  I don't know what kind of object responds to a `peripheral` message but I'm reasonably sure it isn't supposed to be a string.  It looks to me as if some object you need is being released when you don't expect it and iOS has re-used its address to allocate a string.

Comment: The error in the log gives some clue. You can dig into the p.self writeValue method to see where the "peripheral" method (ie selector) is and why is it given a string instead of something else.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers.

I got to fix it.
The problem was that I forgot to initialize the service and characteristic.

I added 'sensorTagIoService.h' and '.m' and initialized it like the other services.

(the values for LED on and off in my question seem to be wrong tho)